# Fastest way to create a fourth row as the sum of the 2 first

Tags: r, rbind

I have a data frame containing the following rows:

```
m <- data.frame(rbind(c(1,4,4),c(2,4,6),c(3,2,6)))
```

I need to create a fourth row, i.e. indexed by `4` as first element of the row, that is the sum of the first two rows.
Desired output:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  4  4
2  2  4  6
3  3  2  6
4  4  8 10
5  5  6 10
6  6 12 14
```

It will continue with a row `5` that is the sum of row `1` and row `3`, a row `6`that is the sum of `1` and '''4'''. What would therefore be the fastest alternative to `rbind()`?

Comment: It is done! I hope it is better

Comment: the letters have no importance, should I remove them?

Comment: yes, but in your description you said, r1, r2, and r3 are index.  Where is the index for r3.  also, the repeating part is not clear

Comment: Done! It will work like a double for loop, but that is a step further.

Comment: ```5``` is ```1+3```

Comment: let me try to understand the pattern, 4 -> 1 + 2, 5 -> 1 + 3, 6 -> 1 + 4 ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Please check my updated solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `for` loop to do this

```
for(i in 1:5)  m[nrow(m) + 1, ] <- m[1, ] + m[nrow(m)-1, ]
m$X1 <- seq_len(nrow(m))
m
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  1  4  4
#2  2  4  6
#3  3  2  6
#4  4  8 10
#5  5  6 10
#6  6 12 14
#7  7 10 14
#8  8 16 18
```

---

It may be also more efficient to expand the dataset with `NA` rows first and then do the assign

```
m <- data.frame(rbind(c(1,4,4),c(2,4,6),c(3,2,6)))
n <- 8
s1 <- (nrow(m) + 1):n
m[s1, 1] <- s1 # creating first column with sequence
#  automatically assigns the other column from 4 to 8 rows to NA
# now we do the assign
for(i in s1) m[i, -1] <- m[1,-1 ] + m[i - 2, -1]
m
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  1  4  4
#2  2  4  6
#3  3  2  6
#4  4  8 10
#5  5  6 10
#6  6 12 14
#7  7 10 14
#8  8 16 18
```

Comment: here the first element of the third row is not the sum of ```r1``` and ```r2``` but the index

Comment: @Simon Not clear.  Please edit your question and show an example using `dput` on the first few rows of dataset